# how to do Hollywood principle between processes in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i was planning to change my project to multiprocesses so i can use more resources,here's my database module code

```
import pymysql
import threading
class tdb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.totalEffected = 0
        pass

    def start(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='xxxx', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxxx', db='xxxx', charset='utf8')

    def select(self,sql,args=None):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql,args)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return result

    def execute(self,sql,args=None):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        result = cur.execute(sql,args)
        cur.close()
        self.totalEffected+=result
        return result

#    def __commit(self,callback):

    def __commitCallback(self,result):
        print('commit result:',result)
        self.conn.close()

    def errorc(self,*args):
        print('error')

    def end(self):
#        init()
#        p.apply_async(self.conn.commit, callback=self.__commitCallback,error_callback=self.errorc)
        if self.totalEffected!=0:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.t)
            thread.start()
        else:
            self.conn.close()

#        p.apply(self.conn.commit)
#        self.conn.close()
#        print('result:' ,result.get())
    def t(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
```

the only operation that really need to handle is  conn.commit(), i use thread to do it ,so i can immediately return. i once use Pool.apply_async(),but it didn't callback, so i want to know how to make the other process call me , so i don't have to spend my time waiting recieve.

Comment: What problem do you have with this code? It would seem that most of the work is done in the database, and the threads you create merely spend their time waiting for `commit` and `close` to finish. Depending on the quality of the database driver, the database threads should unlock the GIL and allow your main threads to continue running.